# WSUS only in https

Tags: windows, bit, windows-update

I have configured my WSUS server on Windows Server 2012 R2, and I want all the communications between the server and the clients in HTTPS.

The problem is even after a proper IIS configuration with HTTPS only activated. The clients seem to try to communicate with both HTTP and HTTPS. More precisely BITS seems to cause this problem. [image: screen1][image: screen2][image: clientConfig]

So is there anyone of you who have managed to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, AFAIK all update packages are digitally signed anyway, so HTTPS isn't particularly critical.

Comment: For sure, but my WSUS server is in the LAN, and some servers on the DMZ are downloading updates from it. It goes throughout an F5 reverse proxy. And I want to ensure than the security is at maximum level between the LAN and the DMZ.

Comment: Last time I checked, the Windows Update client for Windows 7 requires that the server support HTTP.  This is by design, there is no workaround. 
 (Well, you could tunnel it through a VPN I guess.)  I'm not sure about Windows 10 clients, there was a major redesign.